# Getting Tensorflow To Run Faster

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, redhat

I have developed a machine learning python script (let's call it classify_obj written with python 3.6) that imports TensorFlow. It was developed initially for bulk analysis but now I find the need to run this script repeatedly on smaller datasets to cater for more real time usage. I am doing this on Linux RH7.

Process Flow:

1. Master tool (written in Java) call classify_obj with object input to categorize.
2. classify_obj generates the classification result as a csv (takes about 7-10s)
3. Master tool reads the result from #2
4. Master tool proceeds to do other logic
5. Repeat #1 with next object input

To breakdown the time taken, I switched off the main logic and just do the modules import without performing any other action. I found that the import takes about 4-5s out of the 7-10s run time on the small dataset. The classification takes about 2s. I am also looking at other ways to reduce the run time for other areas but the bulk seems to be from the import.

Import time: 4-6s

Classify time: 1s

Read, write and other logic time: 0.2s

I am thinking what options are there to reduce the import time?

One idea I had was to modify the classify_obj into a "stay alive" process. The master tool after completing all its activity will stop this process/service. The intent (not sure if this would be the case) is that all the required libraries are already loaded during the process start and when the master tool calls that process/service, it will only incur the classification time instead of needing to import the libraries repeated.

What do you think about this? Also how can I set this up on Linux RHEL 7.4? Some reference links would be greatly appreciated.

Other suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I designed to achieve the above.

Reference: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

I have to create 2 scripts.
1. client python script: Used to pass the raw data to be classified to the server python script using socket programming.

2. server python script: Loads the keras (tensorflow) lib and model at launch. Continues to stay alive until a 'stop' request from client (to exit the while loop). When the client script sends the data to the server script, server script will process the incoming data and return a ok/not ok output back to the client script.

In the end, the classification time is reduced to 0.1 - 0.3s.

Client Script

```
import socket
import argparse
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='XXXXX')
    parser.add_argument('-i','--input', default='NA',  help='Input txt file path')
    parser.add_argument('-o','--output', default='NA',  help='Output csv path with class')
    parser.add_argument('-stop','--stop', default='no',  help='Stop the server script')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    str = args.input + ',' + args.output + ',' + args.stop

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
    PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    bytedata = str.encode()
    sock.send(bytedata)
    data = sock.recv(1024)

    print('Received', data)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Server Script

```
def main():

    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
    PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

    sock =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((HOST,PORT))
    sock.listen(5)

    stop_process = 'no'
    while (stop_process == 'no'):
        # print('Waiting for connection')
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        data = ''
        try:
            # print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
               data = conn.recv(1024)
               if data:
                   stop_process = process_input(data)     # process_input function processes incoming data. If client sends 'yes' for the stop argument, the stop_process variable will be set to 'yes' by the function.
                   byte_reply = stop_process.encode()
                   conn.sendall(byte_reply)               # send reply back to client
               else:
                   break
            conn.close()
            # print('Closing connection',addr)
        finally:
            conn.close()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```